# Interface Builder Can't Find Any Outlets or Actions

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I think this problem has only been introduced since upgrading to XCode 6.4. I have a storyboard which was working fine (and still is), but interface builder can't see any of the outlets or actions when I right-click on one of my view controllers.

It looks like this:

[image]

I can now only create new connections to outlets/actions by command-dragging from (for example) a button, to the code file. This works, though afterwards it also shows a yellow triangle next to it.

If I drag a standard view controller on to the storyboard, e.g. a navigation view controller, then when I right-click I CAN see all of its outlets etc, it's only with the classes which I've written.

It does work, but it's a pain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what fixed it, but I cleared derived data, uninstalled and reinstalled xcode, and restarted my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue using XCode 10 where all my outlets went yellow triangle and I couldn't control+drag to existing IBActions. The cause was "File's Owner" had its CustomClass property cleared (no value) for some reason. To fix, make sure you have something like this:

SuperDuperViewController.xib ==> Placeholders > File's Owner > Custom Class = "SuperDuperViewController"

This [Apple Dev thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25180) is helpful for other more obscure reasons.